# C3P0 max statements configuration?

Tags: java, c3p0

I am using C3P0. i have below configuration. i need to cache the statements.

```
maxPoolSize="20" 
minPoolSize="6" 
acquireIncrement="3"
initialPoolSize="3"
maxStatements="2000"
```

here i have set `maxStatements` to `2000`. `maxPoolSize` is `20`. does it mean total 2000*20=40000 statements wil be cached?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

no `maxStatements` is the global cache max size.

`maxStatementsPerConnection` is the per connection value.

[Relevant section the c3p0 docs](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#maxStatements)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply! if i dont set maxStatementsPerConnection value then no statements are cached?

Comment: set at least one of the two. You can set both to provide a per connection limit as well as a global limit